# Calculating the time difference between a particular custom event and the next immediate instance of 'session_start'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery. I want to get the average time difference between two events: 'Notification_save_button_pressed' and 'session_start'.

Please note the event 'Notification_save_button_pressed' should come first, and then we should look at how long it took the user to start the immediate next session, i.e 'session_start'.

My table has the following columns (only relevant ones are mentioned here):

user_pseudo / event_name / event_timestamp

Please note, the ‘event_timestamp’ is in a format where the following code snippet works:

```
select DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), day) as day
```

Here is my code so far:

```
WITH EventPairs AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    event_timestamp AS save_button_timestamp,
    LEAD(event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS next_event_timestamp
  FROM
    `table_name`
  WHERE
    event_name = 'Notification_save_button_pressed'
)
,

results as (

SELECT
EventPairs.user_pseudo_id,
  

AVG (timestamp_diff(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(next_event_timestamp), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(save_button_timestamp), second)) AS average_time_difference_seconds

FROM
  EventPairs
JOIN
  `table_name`
ON
  EventPairs.user_pseudo_id = `table_name`.user_pseudo_id
WHERE
  `table_name`.event_name = 'session_start'
GROUP BY
  user_pseudo_id

)
,
time_diff_seconds as
( 
select avg(average_time_difference_seconds) as avg_time_difference_seconds from results
)

select avg_time_difference_seconds/3600 as avg_time_diff_hours from time_diff_seconds
```

The issue is that the result of the query is avg_time_diff_hours = 2.54.

This is not plausible since the time difference should be higher than this. Is there something wrong with my query?